# Moving logic from view to model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to be better about keeping logic out of my views and in my models. I am building a Rails app. It has a `Review` model and an `Album` model. This is some logic in the `album/show.html.erb` view. I would like to move this to the `Review` model, but I am unsure about how to do it.

```
<% @reviews.each do |r| %>
  <div>
    <div class="review-rating" data-number="<%= r.rating %>">
    </div>
    <p class="white"><%= r.comment %></p>
    <p class="grey"><i>posted <%= time_ago_in_words(r.created_at) %> ago</i></p> 
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <% if current_user.id == r.user_id %> 
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_album_review_path(@album, r.id), class: 'grey' %> |
        <%= link_to 'Delete', album_review_path(@album, r.id), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: 'grey' %>
        <br /><br />
      <% end %> 
    <% else %> 
      <br />
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Specifically, I would like to move this part

```
<p class="grey"><i>posted <%= time_ago_in_words(r.created_at) %> ago</i></p>
```

I am getting hung up on the fact that the code relies on the `.each` method. I am unsure how to work around that in the model. I tried this:

```
<p class="grey"><i><%= time_posted(r) %></i></p>
```

with this in the `review.rb` model

```
def time_posted(r)
  "posted  #{time_ago_in_words(r.created_at)} ago"
end
```

But then Rails throws this error:

> "undefined method `time_posted' for #<#:0x007fff2ab8a8e0>"

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this [gem](https://github.com/drapergem/draper).

Comment: Before you get too over-eager on this, remember that display concerns like that aren't really supposed to be expressed in the model. These are generally best put into the `helpers/` area. What you're doing here is very difficult to localize.

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing wrong about keeping **view** logic in views. In your case you're iterating reviews and formatting it the way you want to present it to a user. Think about it, if you would like to change the way you show "posted" to, lets say, **ago in digits**, where is logical place to go and modify it? Model? Don't think so, model keep and operate with data, view represent it, so you example seem's fine to me.

Comment: Right, _database_ and _background_ logic should be removed from the views. The model is the place for that. The controller presents the view and database objects and manages the interaction between them. For example, if a user wants to re-sort a column (although sort may be a bad example...), this should probably happen in the view and not the Model. Meaning, you shouldn't re-query the database with a different `.order`  just to show it differently in a view.

Answer (score 1):

Lets put the discussion aside for a second and look at how we could salvage your attempt:

```
class Review
  def time_posted
    "posted  #{ time_ago_in_words(self.created_at) } ago"
  end
end
```

We have changed the method so that it works on `self` - meaning the object to which the method belongs:

```
<p class="grey"><i><%= r.time_posted %></i></p>
```

However its pretty iffy - we moved the logic from the view but we stuffed it into the model. The models job is to keep track of the business logic, and when you consider how much is actually shoved into the models in rails (validations, callbacks, I18n, associations, state tracking, etc) shoving presentation logic in the as well becomes pretty unappealing.

So what can you do?

#### 1. Create a helper method:

```
module ReviewHelper
  def time_posted(r)
    "posted  #{ time_ago_in_words(r.created_at) } ago"
  end
end

<p class="grey"><i><%= time_posted(r) %></i></p>
```

Basically helpers are just modules - rails takes all the helpers declared in `/app/helpers` and uses them to extend the **view context** so that you can call them from your views. Its simple and keeps the view logic tucked away.

#### 2. use the [presenter pattern](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-presenters/):

```
class ReviewPresenter < SimpleDelegator
  def time_posted(r)
    "posted  #{ time_ago_in_words(r.created_at) } ago"
  end
end

class Review
  def present 
    @presenter ||= ReviewPresenter.new(self)
  end
end
```

---

```
<% @reviews.map(:present).each do |r| %>
  <p class="grey"><i><%= r.time_posted %></i></p> 
<% end %>
```

This makes it nice and encapsulated and avoids putting tons of methods into the "global" view context namespace like a helper does. But if its worth the extra complexity is up to you.

There are several gems which supposedly make the presenter pattern easier to work with like [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper).